# python/django validate email

Tags: python, django, validation, email

i'd like to validate an email address in django, I'm using validate_email and this is the function i wrote.

```
def check_email(self, email):
    # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    import re
    try:
        return validate_email(email)
    except:
        return False
```

Here is where this is function is called

```
    deco = mapped_data['email_receiving']
    email = deco.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
    if not self.check_email(email):
       return Response({"errors": {"error": ["Incorrect email address!"]}}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The validation seems to be buggy, return 404 even though the email is correct, any help ?

Comment: Where is this check_email defined? Is it in a class?

Comment: @RajKris, Yes it is in a class a viewset class, using  DRF

Comment: Maybe try printing the exception in the except clause. Can give you some insight on what exception is getting raised.

Comment: `except: return False` is a sure way to NOT know what could have gone wrong. Bare except clauses should actually be illegal FWIW. Also, without the definition of `validate_email` nor the email values that _should_ pass, it's impossible to help you.

Answer (score 0):

For practical purposes one may use a ready made EmailValidator:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/validators/#emailvalidator

If it is for learning purposes, please, announce that: I may find a regex for this or something.

Comment: Issue solved, just refined my function and here we go ... https://jstricks.com/how-to-validate-email-in-django/

Comment: What Django version do you use? I gave you a modern solution.

Comment: using 1.8.6 currently